# Creating a Wordpress multisite inside a subsite directory

Tags: wordpress, webfaction

I'm using webfaction and I created a wordpress 'app' inside asite.com domain, named "monu". So monu resides in http://asite.com/monu.

Now I'd like to create multiple sites within the monu app: http://asite.com/monu/site1, http://asite.com/monu/site2, etc...

If I try to create this, when I'm creating the sites I receive this message "The internet address of your network will be mysite.". But that's not what I want.

I don't know how to do this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a network (WP multisite) in a directory it would automatically set the network sites as sub-directories.

If you has installed the network right you should have no issues.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network